# Sub menu is cutoff in navigation menu

Tags: css, navigation, overflow, submenu

My sub-menu is cut off in my navigation menu.  I know it has something to do with the overflow:hidden line of css in the navbar id, but if I remove that, the pagecontainer magically gets some major padding

Here is my code:

```
<div id="pagecontainer">
<div id="header">
    <div id="navmenu">
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="doctool"><a href="#">Docs and Tools</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">OnCore</a></li>
                </ul>
         </div>
    </div>  
<!-- Close Header --></div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="Footer"></div>
```

I'm having trouble putting my css in properly, so here's the link to my , [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naimickmac23/vG7Eg/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow:hidden;` from `#navmenu`

Then instead of using margins for `#navmenu` use padding:

```
#navbar{
  padding-top:132px;
  width:700px;
  height:40px;
  padding-left:140px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DYF6U/

I believe this has to do with margins collapsing on each other and pushing the parent down. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here's some documentation on collapsing margins if your interested http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't think of this, but it looks like that works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this will effect the layout of your page, but if you increase the height of #navmenu then the submenu will no longer be cutoff.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vG7Eg/4/)

Code adjustment:

```
#navmenu {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 980px;
  background-image:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3876653/header.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  height:300px; /*Edit this value to allow room for sub menu items*/
}
```

If there are elements directly below the nav bar that get pushed down, then you may need to adjust those accordingly.

Comment: thanks, I didn't think of this. I usually don't make navs with images and I guess I was thinking adjusting the height would mess with my bar height, but obviously it won't because it's an image. I'll check to see how it effects the layout.Thanks